# locale-gen and locales issue

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I am running Ubuntu 12.04. I was trying to install vsftpd and some error appears. Trying to install other packages using apt-get also gives the same error. Here are the details:

```
sudo apt-get install vsftpd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 language-pack-en-base : Depends: locales (>= 2.3.6)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I ran apt-get -f install as suggested and here is the result:

```
apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  locales
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  locales
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 758 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 3957 kB of archives.
After this operation, 16.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  locales
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main locales all 2.19-11
  Could not resolve 'ftp.us.debian.org'
Failed to fetch http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/glibc/locales_2.19-11_all.deb  Could not resolve 'ftp.us.debian.org'
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I then tried running it with --fix-missing:

```
apt-get -f install --fix-missing
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  locales
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  locales
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 758 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 3957 kB of archives.
After this operation, 16.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  locales
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main locales all 2.19-11
  Could not resolve 'ftp.us.debian.org'
Failed to fetch http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/glibc/locales_2.19-11_all.deb  Could     not resolve 'ftp.us.debian.org'
Unable to correct missing packages.
E: Aborting install.
```

I also cannot install locales or even language packages. Also, running locale-gen returns this:

```
locale-gen
The program 'locale-gen' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
apt-get install locales
```

So, I am really out of any other ideas to try. I cannot install any packages using apt-get. All errors are related to this locales.

What are my options now?

Comment: Locales isn't your problem, its the fact you cannot connect to your repo, so this is a network problem - check if you are connected to the internet, check default route and check your DNS, ping  ftp.us.debian.org and do an nslookup ftp.us.debian.org and post the outputs

Comment: Ping gives this: unknown host ftp.us.debian.org and nslookup gives this: ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

Comment: and I am connected to the internet

Comment: the fact NSlookup is replying with no servers could be reached means that your DNS is either wrong or the DNS server you connect to is down, try changing your DNS to googles public DNS (8.8.8.8) and see if nslookup and ping work with that adress then

Comment: Do u mean changing it on the machine I am using now or the cloud server? Because I am connected to the cloud server using SSH

Comment: You really should of worded your question better to include information on whether this was a local or a cloud server... change it on the machine that is having the problem connecting to the apt repo

Comment: Sorry my bad. I forgot to mention that. Let me try ur last suggestions and see if the result is different.

Comment: It was a dependency issue caused by some package update. I have upgraded to 14.04 and that seems to have fixed the issue.